# Running service/task in background when app is closed - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, background-service, background-task

I have mobile app that I build using react native. It requires to check for data in background lets say every 5 seconds even if app is closed.
What can i use for running background process ?

I tried searching for solution and I found libraries that are limited to running service only every 15 minutes.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate

Comment: https://blog.expo.io/how-to-run-background-tasks-in-react-native-e1619acef48f